# The method findOne(Example<S>) in the type QueryByExampleExecutor<Contact> is not applicable for the arguments (Long)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The find methods not working for me but in other project work fine .

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.entities.Contact;

public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long>{

}
```

in my controller i call find one but give works.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/contact/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Contact getContact(@PathVariable Long id){
        return repo.findOne(id); //here give a error
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot do you use? If it is 2.0.2 you should use findById method since it got renamed.

Answer (score 9):

Some CRUD Repository methods got renamed in Spring Data and

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    T findOne(ID id);
```

is one of them. Now you should use the

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

For more info which methods got renamed see this blog [improved-naming-for-crud-repository-methods](https://spring.io/blog/2017/06/20/a-preview-on-spring-data-kay#improved-naming-for-crud-repository-methods)

There is still a findOne method around but this is from

```
public interface QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
    <S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example);
```

which is also an interface of the SimpleJpaRepository. So that is why you got your error, since this method awaits an Example as parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me.